# images in WordPress page templates

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a good way to put images into a theme template so they can be be easily exchanged in WordPress?  I've been trying to use `wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, $size )` but then I would need to somehow maintain the same id from old picture to new picture.

Additionally, `wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, $size )` is picking up auto-cropped thumbnail versions of my image rather than the original. If you can tell me why this is happening, then bonus to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an /images folder within the theme's main folder and then reference the images from within your template file as follows:

```
//inside the template-file.php
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/your_image.jpg " />
```

The structure of your theme files should be something like this:

```
/your_theme_folder
    /images
        your_image.jpg
    template-file.php
```

Comment: This is an okay solution but it doesn't allow me to interface with the Wordpress media library.  Optimally I'd like to do that but this is probably what I'll end up doing.

Comment: It sounds like you want the behavior of the "featured image" option. If you're not already using this feature it will provide exactly the functionality you described. In the template use get_the_post_thumbnail() to place the image.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't think about that.  That's a good idea but I want to have multiple pictures that I can swap in and out.  I can only have one featured image per page but that would be great if you could specify any number of featured images...

Comment: You can do that, but you need to add a custom meta box, which can be a bit tricky (<a href="http://www.farinspace.com/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-meta-box/">here's</a> a tutorial). The end result will look almost the same as the default featured image option. If you decide to pursue that, I strongly recommend using one of the reusable classes for custom meta boxes: http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/

Comment: Or if you're not opposed to relying on a plugin, this one gets it done quick: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/